# Coreの使い方を教えてください。

Tags: ocaml

osxで以下のようにopamでcoreをインストールして

```
opam install core
```

以下のプログラムex01.mlを書いて、

```
open Core.Std

let _ =
  let list = [1;2;3] in
  let rc = List.fold_left list ~init:0 ~f:(fun acc x ->
    acc + x
  ) in
 Printf.printf "%d\n" rc
```

ex01.ml

以下のコマンドでコンパイルすると:

```
$ ocamlfind ocamlopt -package core ex01.ml
```

以下のエラーが表示されます:

```
ocamlfind: Error from package `threads': Missing -thread or -vmthread switch
```

threadsパッケージのスイッチが駄目だと言われてますけど、threadsって何？っていう状況です。

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package core -tag thread ex01.native
```

このように書けば、動いたのですが、omakeを使った場合がやはり分からないのと、
ocamlfindを使った場合の書き方が分かるとうれしいです。

Answer (score 1):

OMakefileも自己解決しました。-threadオプションを付ければよかったようです。

```
.PHONY: all clean
USE_OCAMLFIND = true
FILES[]= ex01
OCAMLPACKS[]=
  core
OCAMLCFLAGS += -thread
OCAMLOPTFLAGS += -thread

.DEFAULT: $(OCamlProgram ex01, $(FILES))
clean:
  rm -f $(filter-proper-targets $(ls R, .))
```